# How can I filter multiple property based on one input model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Says we have a search input which filters data by two properties: name and id

```
<input ng-model="query.name">
<input ng-model="query.id">

<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query"></div>
```

How can I do this in one simple input ng-model

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can write a custom filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple, you are almost there:

```
<input ng-model="query">
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">{{item}}</div>
```

This way you have only one ng-model to filter.

--
**Edit:**

If you have more properties in your object that don't want to be filtered, you can use a **function** or a **custom filter**, from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

> `{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}`
>   `Expression` can be: `string`, `Object` or `function()`

I've updated the fiddle to demonstrate how you can filter using both a **function** and a **custom filter**: <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9s4Lvs4/2/)</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for writing the example, but what if there is other useless properties which I don't want to included, I slightly changed the example: http://jsfiddle.net/k9s4Lvs4/1/

Comment: @klamtlne, I've edited my answer to add a new fiddle for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but it looks like from the docs at
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
that you can do something like this:

```
<input ng-model="query.$">
```

See the last example on the page and the part that talks about the "Object" version of the "expression" argument to the filter.

Comment: This's a gr8 resolution for this example, but real-life, there are some useless properties which will also be included this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem with `angular-filter`.

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.users = [
  { first_name: 'Sharon', last_name: 'Melendez' },
  { first_name: 'Edmundo', last_name: 'Hepler' },
  { first_name: 'Marsha', last_name: 'Letourneau' }
];
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model="search" placeholder="search by full name"/>
<th ng-repeat="user in users | searchField: 'first_name': 'last_name' | filter: search">
  {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
</th>
<!-- so now you can search by full name -->
```

As simple as that.

Good Luck.